# Capture Screencast hiddenly?

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I have a computer which others access via TeamViewer. Right now, this computer is Windows based.

I am looking to record my visitors secretly into a video for security purposes. I do not want them to know that I am recording them.

Is there a software that allows me to do so?

Comment: Is there any price limitation?

Comment: Price is not a limitation

Comment: Beware of the legal implications of doing this. As soon as you mention it to those you are monitoring, some of them might get "lawyered-up", so make certain that you cannot be legally prosecuted by those whom you will upset by spying on them. https://law.stackexchange.com/ as a first step, but you probably want to see a local lawyer too

Answer (score 1):

[Hidden Capture](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hidden-capture/) seems to be a tool you might have a look at.

- it records the screen
- it works on Windows *)
- it's free
- the "Hide and wait" button makes it invisible, i.e. hides the window. It will still be visible in Task Manager as a background process called `HC.exe`. **)

Be aware: when trying to download in a company, the website or the tool may be detected as "hacking tool" or "unwanted software". Your administrator might get a notice of this.

*) On Windows 10 I had some difficulties. The program was not able to write its settings file. Once I changed the security settings of the installation directory, it worked.

**) If not, it would need to be a kernel mode driver, not an application. Such things are much more dangerous and can cause bluescreens if not implemented correctly. If you like it to be less obvious, you can rename the executable.

Comment: "•the "Hide and wait" button makes it invisible" - invisible how? For instance, does it still show up in Task Manager? Upvote, though, as it seems a good candidate.

Comment: @Mawg: thanks, I clarified your question in the answer